# Multithreading in Service layer in Java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am designing web app with Spring MVC.

I have some problem in implementing safely updating e-mail and registering new user.
E-mail is unique for every user.

It is my method, which is invoked by controller for registering user:

```
@Override
    public void registerUser(Client newUser) throws DuplicateEmailException {

        if(!isEmailUnique(newUser.getEmail())){
            throw new DuplicateEmailException("User with the same email is registered"
                    + " in system already");
        }

        newUser.setPassword(encodePassword(newUser.getPassword()));
        newUser.setRole(UserRole.ROLE_CLIENT);
        newUser.setStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
        newUser.setEmailStatus(EmailStatus.NOTCONFIRMED);
        newUser.setRegistrationTime(LocalDateTime.now());

        clientDao.save(newUser);


    }
```

It is method for updating email:

```
@Override
    public void updateUserEmail(String email, String newEmail, String password)
            throws InvalidPasswordException, DuplicateEmailException {
        Client client = getClientByEmail(email);
        if(!isPasswordRight(password, client.getPassword())){
            throw new InvalidPasswordException("Password doesn't match to real");
        }

        if(email.equals(newEmail)){
            return;
        }

        if(!isEmailUnique(newEmail)){
            throw new DuplicateEmailException(
                    "Such email is registered in system already");
        }

        client.setEmail(newEmail);
        client.setEmailStatus(EmailStatus.NOTCONFIRMED);
    }
```

There is can be situation, when some user clicks button for registering, `registerUser(Client newUser)` method checks email for uniqueness, at the same moment second user want to update email, and before `clientDao.save(newUser)` is invoked, `updateUserEmail(String email, String newEmail, String password)` checks email for uniqueness, and if emails of both users are equals, I will get two the same emails in db - it is unacceptable.

My Service layer is marked with `@Translactional` annotation, session is automatically flushed before closing transaction, and user is saved in db only after finishing `registerUser(..)` method

So, tell me please, which instruments in Java multithreading can I use for solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this programmatically by rolling the isEmailUnique method into the save functionality and making the save method synchronized.

**BUT** the better solution is to make the email column have a unique constraint in the db, to make sure that no duplicates can ever make it into your dataset no matter where in the app, or even which app, they come from.

Comment: But in my updating email method I don't using save method, I get Client instance from db and set fields on this persistent instance.

Comment: Handling uniqueness problems is something you really want to avoid doing in the app if you can manage it. This is because even if you solve the concurrency problem within one JVM, if you scale horizontally to multiple instances of the app you now need to manage concurrency across multiple apps, which can be a very hard problem to solve. I strongly suggest you handle this on the DB side.

Comment: So, I catch exception, which is invoked if I attempt to save object with duplicated email. Thanks:)

Comment: but I'm gonna leave isEmailUnique method for reducing number of queries in db. It is right decision?

Comment: I'm not sure what the isEmailUnique method is doing, but if that method isn't making a db call then doing what you suggest should save on db calls.

Comment: How can I catch DataIntegrityViolationException, if I have two different forms(registering and updating email), which can throw this exception. I must return registering form with error message when user wants to register existed email, and for for updating email, when user wants to update his email. How can I do this??

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with your application to give exact details but from looking at your snippets I would recommend wrapping statements that can result in an update to the email with try-catches for the DataIntegrityViolationException and in the catch block you can re-throw the exception as a DuplicateEmailException. From there it should be handled by the application as normal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this solution)